# Is an NTFS compressed drive really written compressed under Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ntfs, compression

I want to copy a very big NTFS compressed drive under Ubuntu since it copies faster than Windows. I formatted the new drive with `mkfs` under Ubuntu and after a while the target drive ran out of space. That was weird since both drives are exactly the same model from the manufacturer. My guess is that since the first drive is compressed and the second one was not, the data could not fit.

After looking for how to format a drive and mark it as compressed under Ubuntu I gave up and did that on a Windows machine. The second drive is now marked as compressed but as far as I know, such compression is just a bit marker in the file system that prompts Windows to compress when writing to the disc. Stated another way, it is the operating system that decides to compress the data.

Will Ubuntu compress the data when writing to my second (now compressed) drive? I'm using the standard *ntfs-3g* driver.

*Update:* found [this link](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-232452.html) that claims that Ubuntu indeed does not compress.

look for *mpg187* comment

*Update:* from [ntfs-3g site](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/)

> ntfs-3g is an NTFS driver, which can create, remove, rename, move files, directories, hard links, and streams; it can read and write files, including streams and sparse files; it can handle special files like symbolic links, devices, and FIFOs; moreover it can also read and create transparently compressed files. It comes in two variants ntfs-3g and lowntfs-3g with a few differences mentioned below in relevant options descriptions. The volume to be mounted can be either a block device or an image file.

It seems the answer to this question is yes but I'm still not sure.

Comment: The speed of hard disk reads & writes should be the same under any OS, the fact that it was much slower in Windows probably means it was using compression. But doesn't windows report the actual size of the files, whether or not they're compressed by NTFS? If you tried to copy say 10G of files to another drive, you should see 10G of files copied. Unless you had millions of tiny files (like 10 or 20 bytes) that take up much more disk space than their added together sizes, or they were compressed

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [ntfs-3g ubuntu manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/ntfs-3g.8.html), you can see the option:

```
compression
              This  option enables creating new transparently compressed files
              in directories marked for compression. A directory is marked for
              compression  by  setting  the  bit  11 (value 0x00000800) in its
              Windows attribute. In such a directory, new  files  are  created
              compressed  and  new  subdirectories  are  themselves marked for
              compression. The option and the flag have no effect on  existing
              files. Currently this is the default option.
```

The key here is: This is the default option. So, apparently the default is to compress files marked for compression and everything inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy a compressed drive for speed, you should consider copying a VHD or ISO, or even a partition.

Copying from one compressed drive to another will always decompress, copy, recompress.  Unless you use a compressed sync protocol, in which case the process will be:

```
decompress
compress
copy
decompress
compress
```